# Google Drive API statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-keystore

I have problem with Google Drive. 
After I'm clicking on dialog with email Im getting error:

```
statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED
```

I resolved this problem by adding in gradle

```
 debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }

signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias '******'
        keyPassword '******'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/.android/debug.keystore')
        storePassword '******'
    }
}
```

But the question is it is possible to work without this file and this options in gradle?

I'm pushing this code to repository and tests are failed in case of missing debug.keystore file.

**Code will be published and I'm not sure can also share this debug.keystore file?**

I know the easiest is to add this file in to directory app and change the path.

**But maybe someone know better solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding in gradle

```
debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }

signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias '******'
        keyPassword '******'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/.android/debug.keystore')
        storePassword '******'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Authorizing and Using REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth) which shows how to authorize with Google and use Google REST APIs when you want your app to access Google APIs with the user's Google account over HTTP. There are also given approaches that you may try for your app.

Check the following to authorize your Android app:

1. Configure build dependencies in your app's root-level `build.gradle` file.
2. Use the Google-Provided authorization UI for REST API access. Use the `Auth.GoogleSignInApi` method to give users of your Android app a Google-provided authorization UI that handles all of this.

   - Specify scopes by creating a [`GoogleSignInOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#GoogleSignInOptions.Builder()) object with the new scopes that you want to request by calling [`GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.requestScopes`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#requestScopes(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope...)).
   - You can get an Android Account object as part of your Google Sign-In result, and you can later instantiate a `GoogleAccountCredential` object with it.
3. Use [`GoogleAccountCredential`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential)  and the client library for REST API access.

For more information, please also see [Authorizing Android Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth).